# InvocationTargetException caused by NullPointer in basic javafx application

Tags: java, linux, javafx, gtk, javafx-3d

I'm trying to follow this javafx 3d [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-3d-shapes-example/), however I get the following error (I cleared up several earlier errors by installing 32bit gtk2 packages and libraries), however this issue doesn't seem to be down to that. I have found nothing online with the same error.

Note: I don't have an fxml file (I don't think I need one as I set it all up in code)

Running ubuntu 16.04.3 Elementary OS Loki

Error message:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
... 5 more
```

Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.PointLight;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GraphicsApplication extends Application {

public void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Box box = new Box(100,100,100);
    box.setTranslateX(150);
    box.setTranslateY(100);

    PointLight light = new PointLight();
    light.setTranslateX(300);
    light.setTranslateY(350);
    light.setTranslateZ(200);

    PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
    camera.setTranslateX(100);
    camera.setTranslateY(-50);
    camera.setTranslateZ(300);

    Group root = new Group(box, light);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200, true);
    scene.setCamera(camera);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Super test 5000");
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Is that the complete stack trace?

Comment: Yeah, none of it is from my code explicitly:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`main()` method has to be `static`.

Comment: Don't feel too bad; just lost an hour or so after falling in the same trap too. The IDE should warn about this kind of thing.